# How to save and use a trained model in keras and python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

we want to save a trained model that we can use it in an application. So the problem is that if we load the model, the accuracy is pretty low. see the code below.

To save the model:

```
    model.save("TrainedModel\\emotionDetector.h5")
```

To load the model:

```
    model = models.load_model("TrainedModel\\emotionDetector.h5")
    loss, acc = model.evaluate(X,  y, verbose=1)
    print('Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%'.format(100*acc), loss)
```

Accuracy and loss before saving:
loss: 0.2324 - accuracy: 0.9202 - val_loss: 1.3789 - val_accuracy: 0.6353

Accuracy and loss after loading:
Restored model, accuracy: 36.92% Loss:  nan

So we know, that there is a different between model.fit() and model.evaluate(). How can we improve this result of model.evaluate or do we have to train the model again after starting the application?

Please help us! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The model that is produced in model.fit() will be exactly the same as the model you loaded afterwards and used to do model.evaluate. Are you using the exact same data to evaluate?

(Note that the values given by Keras during training are averaged estimates, there will always be a difference between that and what you get when you call model.evaluate())

Comment: Yes, we are using exactly the same data.

Comment: You have to use `evaluate` in both tests, you can't use `fit` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Architecture of the model, some layers might not be active during evaluation. Such layers could be Dropout or BatchNormalization. Due to this results could be different.